# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement the spring security log in and I have tried something like :

```
spring-security.xml:
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="lokesh" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

 <listener>  
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
 </listener>  



 <!-- Spring Security -->  
 <filter>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
 </filter>  

 <filter-mapping>  
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>
```

I am using spring version:3.1 and I am getting the error in above xml file .

error:

```
May 5, 2014 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.MatcherType.<clinit>(MatcherType.java:22)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder.<init>(HttpConfigurationBuilder.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.createFilterChain(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 28 more
May 5, 2014 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 5, 2014 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/HRportal] startup failed due to previous errors
May 5, 2014 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 5, 2014 12:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:534)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4380)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Can anyone correct me I am wrong somewhere?

Comment: @geoand Referring to code on external sites is discouraged for a number of reasons, especially because it breaks the essence of the question apart. The stack trace alone has sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @chrylis I totally see your point, but some times it is not possible to resolve the issue with the stacktrace alone. For instance there is no definitive way to know what dependencies are on OP's classpath. If for example the code works for me, then we definitely know that he/she has setup the project on his/her machine incorrectly. Like I said, I see your point, but the end is to help the user and inform future readers

Comment: @user3448105 which build tool you use? like maven, Ant etc. and which spring-security version? try clean once and build again, and also conform that class is available on buildpath by clicking ctrl+shift+t and type `AntPathRequestMatcher` and see if anything you got?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing `spring-security-web-3.1.X.RELEASE.jar` from your classpath

Comment: No I am not messing the sepring-security-web-3.0 jar...I have it in the lib folder...something else is wrong..

Comment: Then please provide further information regarding this error. From the provided log file it seems that you are having an issue with a missing library.

Comment: @user3448105 : In your stacktrace, the relevant info seems to be `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher`. In SpringSecurity 3.1, `AntPathRequestMatcher` is in `spring-security-web-3.1.X.RELEASE.jar` so the answer of Pantelis. You should control if for **your** release of SpringSecurity it is in a jar that is in your path. And you should tell what is your release ...

Comment: The missing class: AntPathRequestMatcher.class is introduced in 3.1. Can you please check that you are using the correct version? Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher.html

Answer (score 2):

It happen if there are two more `ContextLoaderListener` exist in your project.

For ex: in my case 2 `ContextLoaderListener` was exist using

1. java configuration
2. web.xml

So, remove any one `ContextLoaderListener` from your project and run your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you haven't messed the jar, then please clean the project and perform `mvn clean install`. This should solve the problem.